# ssh starting a command such as mutt

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Why does the following not work from one ubuntu machine to anohter

```
ssh  user@host mutt
```

(it just sits there doing nothing)

Whereas the following is fine

```
ssh  user@host ls
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the `-t` option to `ssh`, to force it to allocate a pseudo-terminal.  For more information, see section 7.4.5.5 of [SSH: The definitive guide](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch07_04.htm).

Comment: @coneslayer  - I had seen the pseudo-terminal but didnt understand what it really did. This does the trick for me